# Какие способы наладить систему приоритетов в очереди на вызов метода(обычно synchronized) существуют?

Tags: java, многопоточность, приоритет

Грубо говоря, существует метод со следующей сигнатурой:

```
 private static synchronized void process(Object object);
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было поставить какой-то определенный объект в очередь перед всеми другими ожидающими доступа.
Вот одна из реализаций определенной идеи, решающей эту задачу:

```
public class PriorAccess {
    private static ConcurrentLinkedDeque<Object> deque;
    private static Object addNotifier;

    static {
        deque = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<Object>();
        addNotifier = new Object();
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                synchronized(addNotifier){
                    if (!deque.isEmpty()) {
                        process();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            addNotifier.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private static void process(){
        Object toProcess = deque.poll();
        System.out.println("Processing...");
    }

    public static void process(Object object){
        deque.addLast(object);
        synchronized(addNotifier){
            addNotifier.notify();
        }
    }

    public static void processWithHighPriority(Object object){
        deque.addFirst(object);
        synchronized(addNotifier){
            addNotifier.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

А вот реализация этой же идеи но с применением технологий, советуемых товарищем [Drawn Raccoon](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/276430/drawn-raccoon), но уже с возможностью точно указывать приоритет:

```
public class PriorAccess {
    private static PriorityBlockingQueue<Element> queue;

    static {
        queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Element>(11, (e1, e2) -> e2.priority - e1.priority);
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    process();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private static void process() throws InterruptedException {
        Object toProcess = queue.take().getObject();
        System.out.println("Processing...");
    }

    public static void process(Object object){
        process(object, Element.MIDDLE_PRIORITY);
    }

    public static void process(Object object, int priority){
        queue.add(new Element(object, priority));
    }

    private static class Element{
        private Object object;
        private int priority;

        public final static int HIGH_PRIORITY;
        public final static int MIDDLE_PRIORITY;
        public final static int LOW_PRIORITY;

        static {
            HIGH_PRIORITY = 10;
            MIDDLE_PRIORITY = 5;
            LOW_PRIORITY = 0;
        }

        public Element(Object object, int priority) throws IllegalArgumentException{
            if(0 > priority || 10 < priority){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            this.object = object;
            this.priority = priority;
        }

        public Object getObject() {
            return this.object;
        }

        public void setObject(Object object) {
            this.object = object;
        }

        public int getPriority() {
            return this.priority;
        }

        public void setPriority(int priority) {
            this.priority = priority;
        }

    }
}
```

Как еще можно решить эту задачу? Не обязательно реализацию - подскажите идею.

Comment: `Как еще можно решить эту задачу?` Использовать очередь с приоритетом (PriorityBlockingQueue вместо ConcurrentLinkedDeque)?

Comment: @Drawn Raccoon нет, не в этом смысле. Сам принцип - например, сделать так, чтобы вообще это работало без стороннего потока

Comment: Хотя, несомненно, если реализовывать ваше предложение, код станет много проще. BlockingQueue - вещь однако. Спасибо

Comment: Только тут нужно какой-то параметр ввести - по которому приоритет определять